# get one variable out of database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, url, get

Ok obviously i'm a beginner.

What i'm trying to do here is probably simple.
I'm trying to get all the field of my database to echo on my website. So i use this to show only the basic details:

```
<?php
 // Make a MySQL Connection
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("crnew") or die(mysql_error());

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM releases") 
 or die(mysql_error());  

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )
 ) {
      // Print out the contents of each row into a table

echo '<ul class="releaselist">';
echo '<li>';
echo $row['products_name'];
echo '</li>';
echo '<li>';
echo $row['products_title']; 
echo '</li>';
echo '<li>';
echo '<a href="detailed.php?products_id="><img class="releaseimg"      src="'.$row['products_image'].'"></a>';
echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';


 } 

 ?>
```

So far eveything works fine.
What i want to do with this is get my URL to look like this when i click on a single image.

www.mywebsite.com/detailed.php?id=1

and show everything available in the table RELEASES

The way i've done it which is not working is:

```
 <?php

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("crnew") or die(mysql_error());

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM releases
                    WHERE products_id=products_id") 
 or die(mysql_error());  

 if ($result){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $_GET['products_id'];  

}

?>
```

Comment: You will need a form to do this

Comment: The way you access that variable is with GET: `$_GET['id']`

Comment: @Fabio - not reeded. just parse the `$_GET` and pass that as a parameter to the query

Comment: @karthikr do you mean to pass id directly in anchor url?

Comment: `where products_id=products_id` just evaluates to true and gives you all rows. Try `'select * from releases where products_id = ' . intval($_GET['id'])`. Be sure to check if `$_GET['id']` is set before selecting.

Comment: are those are from 2 different file?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly, and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Using an interface like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) will make it easier to construct [properly escaped SQL queries](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and will ensure your code works in the future as PHP is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your first script needs to be updated to:

```
echo '<a href="detailed.php?id=' . $row['products_id'] . '><img class="releaseimg"      src="'.$row['products_image'].'"></a>';
```

That will turn your image into a link. At that point your second script should be able to use:

```
_GET['id']
```

to retrieve this value and use it in your query. Thusly:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM releases
                    WHERE products_id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
```

Now if you really want to products_id in the URL instead of id, just change it 'id' to products_id in the echo line in the first script and all of the $_GET uses in the second script.

Comment: Ok this works but it only show the products_id which is probably normal because i only have this: `echo $_GET['id'];`

But if i want to show all the info, for instance the products_name,why does: `echo $_GET['products_name'];` doesn't work?

Comment: Ok i got it to work. I replaced `echo $_GET['products_name'];` by `echo $row['products_name'];`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
echo '<a href="detailed.php?products_id="><img class="releaseimg"      src="'.$row['products_image'].'"></a>';
```

To this one:

```
echo "<a href='detailed.php?products_id=".$row['products_id']."'><img class='releaseimg'      src='".$row['products_image']."'></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try using $row['products_id'] instead of $_GET['products_id']; $_GET is used when accessing a webpage and the reason that $row['products_image'] worked is because you accessed the database results.

Answer (score -1):

You have misplaced the use of products_id...

Your code should like something like this...

```
 <?php

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("crnew") or die(mysql_error());

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM releases
                    WHERE products_id='".intval($_GET['id'])."'") 
 or die(mysql_error());  

 if ($result){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['products_id'];  

}

?>
```

Comment: His code should not look like that, you have left him wide open to an SQL injection attack. Not a good practice to be teaching new coders.

Comment: Never trust user input. You should at least add intval() to avoid problems with query.

Comment: it's just to show where to use the `$_GET` value. But you're all right. =)

Comment: Sorry to have missed out on that guys... just wanted to tell him where he's going wrong... Have followed your inputs and edited the code.

Comment: `intval` is not a general purpose escaping strategy. Please, use `mysql_real_escape_string` and do it right.

Comment: intval has been used expecting products_id to be an integer value. If it is something other than an integer... we can use the general purpose escaping strategy